# USB Microscope on Mac / ChromeOS / Linux

Tags: linux, usb, drivers, webcam

I recently got an Aigo GE-5 digital microscope and sadly it is not recognised by any of my OSs as a camera.

The device is seen by the kernel:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#= 20 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1578 ProdID=800d Rev=01.00
S:  Manufacturer=Digital Microscope
S:  Product=USB 2.0 Camera
S:  SerialNumber=GE5-2007-04-12
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=ff Driver=(none)
```

But it seems based on it's USB ID we're unable to link a driver to it. 
The vendor and product IDs are 1578:800d

Just for comparison here's the output for my webcam on one of the laptops:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=03 Cnt=02 Dev#= 19 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0bda ProdID=57cf Rev=00.03
S:  Manufacturer=HD WebCam
S:  Product=HD WebCam
S:  SerialNumber=NC2141103Q632028A6LM03
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
```

Here the uvcvideo driver was correctly assigned to the hardware. 
Soooo the question is can I somehow assign the device based on it's ID to the driver? (without adding the USB ID string to the kernel source for the driver in question and recompiling the kernel - as that, in case of ChromeOS or MacOS cannot work I'm afraid)

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: All i have read says it is not compatible with Linux, Windows xp~W8 and Mac only

Comment: There appears to be Windows XP, Vista and 7 drivers at https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ja&u=http://jp.aigo.com/support/ge5.html&prev=search.

Comment: @Moab, the trouble is that MacOS behaves very similar to ChromeOS (Linux) - it doesn't match up any driver for the given USB Vendor:Product combination. I don't have access to a windows computer and never have used any kind of windows ever hence I wanted to find a solution for this to work on non-windows.

Comment: Should anyone run into the same problem, form the windows driver package I managed to figure out what is the exact type of the chip that's in there.

%USB2750.DeviceDesc% = USB2750,USB\VID_1578&PID_800D

Based on this ID string and also on this signature

eMPIA USB 2.0 Video Devices: EM27xx and EM28xx.

one might safely assume it will be an eMPIA 2750 video chip innit so all I need to do is grab a linux kernel and add the relevant vendor and product ID to the headers of the em27xx USB camera kernel module and build a custom compiled linux kernel that will have this thing enabled.

Comment: have ordered a cheapo old thinkpad off ebay to that above ^^
wish me luck! :) 

I'll update you on how I go (should anyone be interested that is)

Comment: there are some updates related to this shoudl anyone be interested.
What I did is firstly told the kernel that the new_id for an em27xx could be the USB id of the microscope. 
Then played around a bit with the em27xx driver and have specified all of the possible options it provides. 
In some cases the microscope's LED ring even lit up, and the module managed to control the other external light as well, but sadly no picture was seen in any case. 
I would suppose this would be a very small change / addition somewhere in that module's code, didn't play with it that deep.

Comment: so all in all until now it seems I have a *very* fancy desk lamp ;) that can only be turned on if you hack a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue, managed to get mine up and running on Ubuntu 18.04 using guvcview:

```
sudo apt-get install guvcview
dsmeg
guvcview
```

Then change the input on guvcview to the other camera option (I just chose the option that wasn't my laptop webcam)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help here, however in your case the thing is that the kernel itself sees the device whereas in mine it doesn't.